# Replace a string with a javascript code and load it (everything after pageload)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm hosting my blog/website on blogger, I need to insert an ad above any first chapter of any post. I can't modify any single post. I can't place the ad code in the theme html editor just before the post content, because I already have another ad before post content body. 
I try with this 2 codes but none of them work:

1)

```
<script> 
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('<div class="description"', "<div id='toppostrect300x250' class='description'"); 
var container = document.getElementById('toppostrect300x250'); 
var w = document.write; document.write = function (content) {
container.innerHTML = content;
document.write = w; };

var script = document.createElement('script'); script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.src = '//p252740.clksite.com/adServe/banners?tid=252740_484260_6'; document.body.appendChild(script); 
</script>
```

2)

```
 <script>
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('<h3>Chapter 1', "
<script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript' src='//p252740.clksite.com/adServe/banners?tid=252740_484260_6'><\/script>");
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a small "demo" of the result you are trying to achieve? Excluding any information not necessary to the question (such as why you need the result). You should probably also have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [https://imgur.com/a/iuBdC](https://imgur.com/a/iuBdC) take a look of what i need, thanks

Comment: Cheat Bag, I made the mistake of tentatively answering your question without even knowing what your problem actually is. I'm sorry I did that. In your own terms, from this sentence `I try with this 2 codes but none of them work:` what defines `none of them work:`. What's the non-working behavior? Does it throw an error message in the console? Is the script running and failing, or is the script not running at all?

Comment: no errors, when i use the first the replace works but the script is not loaded; when i use the second the replace put the code but is not executed